# Update/insert Trigger triggering the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Articlemaster table .
  I want to update Aging column of ArticleMaster(for ever Insert/update in ArticleMaster) depending on

- The value Month n year column in "NSI_Activation" table.
- The value of Status in "skuSize" table.

Conditions:-

- If Status='R' then Aging='Repeat'

  ### ELSE
- if Month <4 then Aging=CAST(Year as varchar(4))+'1-3'
- If Month>4 then Aging=CAST(Year as varchar(4))+'1-3'

  **1.Is it required to create the trigger for my case or any other possibilities do exists?**

I wrote one trigger but it was updating only 1 record but not for multiple updates.So i tried with creating with temp tables as shown **below**, but its going to infinite loop.

```
ALTER TRIGGER AgingUpdation
   ON  Articlemaster
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
IF ((
SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1 )
RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @i INT, @d INT,@c INT,@month INT;
    DECLARE @MonthTable TABLE(idx bigint Primary key identity(1,1),ArticleCode varchar(30),CompCode varchar(20),MonthNo INT,DateToMarketYear INT,[Status] char(1))
    SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;
    SELECT @d = COUNT(*) FROM deleted;
    insert into  @monthtable(ArticleCode,CompCode,MonthNo,DateToMarketYear,[Status]) 
    Select  I.ArticleCode,I.CompCode,N.DatetoMarketMonth,N.DateToMarketYear,(select top 1 Status from SkuSize S  INNER JOIN Inserted I on S.ArticleCode=I.ArticleCode and S.CompCode=I.CompCode)
     from NSI_Activation N inner join Inserted I on N.ArticleCode=I.ArticleCode and I.Compcode=N.CompCode 
    IF @i + @d > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @i > 0 AND @d = 0    -- Insert
          BEGIN     
                Set @c=1
                While(@c<=(SELECT MAX(idx) from @MonthTable))
                BEGIN
                    if (Select  [Status] from  @MonthTable where idx=@c)='R' 
                    update A set A.Aging='Repeat' from ArticleMaster A 
                    inner join @MonthTable T on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode
                    else If (Select  MonthNo from @MonthTable where idx=@c)<4
                    update A set A.Aging=CAST(T.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_1-3' from ArticleMaster A inner join @MonthTable T  on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode and A.Compcode=T.CompCode 
                    else
                    update A set A.Aging=CAST(T.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_4-12' from ArticleMaster A inner join @MonthTable T  on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode and A.Compcode=T.CompCode 
                END
                set @c=@c+1
           END

        IF @i > 0 AND @d > 0  --Update
            BEGIN
                Set @c=1
                While(@c<=(SELECT MAX(idx) from @MonthTable))
                BEGIN
                    if (Select  [Status] from  @MonthTable where idx=@c)='R' 
                    update A set A.Aging='Repeat' from ArticleMaster A 
                    inner join @MonthTable T on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode
                    else If (Select  MonthNo from @MonthTable where idx=@c)<4
                    update A set A.Aging=CAST(T.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_1-3' from ArticleMaster A inner join @MonthTable T  on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode and A.Compcode=T.CompCode 
                    else
                    update A set A.Aging=CAST(T.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_4-12' from ArticleMaster A inner join @MonthTable T  on A.ArticleCode=T.ArticleCode and A.Compcode=T.CompCode 
                END
                set @c=@c+1
            END
    END    

END
```

I googled a lot but not find the way out.
Fed up with triggers. is there any other possible way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you will be able to use something like this

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.Aging=(CASE 
                   WHEN s.Status='R' THEN 'Repeat'
                   WHEN s.Status!='R' and N.MonthNo <4 THEN CAST(N.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_1-3'
                   WHEN s.Status!='R' and N.MonthNo >=4 THEN CAST(N.DateToMarketYear as varchar(4))+'_4-12'
                   ELSE A.Aging
                 END)
    FROM ArticleMaster A 
    inner join inserted I ON A.ArticleCode=I.ArticleCode and A.Compcode=I.CompCode 
    inner join NSI_Activation N ON N.ArticleCode=I.ArticleCode and N.Compcode=I.CompCode 
    inner join SkuSize S ON S.ArticleCode=I.ArticleCode and S.Compcode=I.CompCode
```

Comment: could there be a typo with the second "<"? could that be ">=" instead?

Comment: I could not ALTER the trigger as its taking more then 20 min, and cannot delete/drop also , while trying to do this from Designer mode it shows erroe as ->"LOCK request timeout period exceeded."

Comment: Seems like another transaction is holding a lock on a required resources (table/view..). You can follow instructions in following url. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337412%28v=sql.105%29.aspx